# What's wrong with "My next steps could be as follows"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, modal-verbs

What's wrong with the sentence "My next steps **could** be as follows: blah-blah-blah"?

It has always seemed OK to me, but today I've noticed, that Google suggests using "would" instead of "could" here. So, is "My next steps **would** be ..." really more appropriate?

Comment: What does Google know about what you're trying to say that you don't know better?

Comment: I'm just trying to be sure that there is no any grammatical errors in using "could" in this case. I was also confused with the fact that Google search didn't find any example of using "could" in this sentence, everybody uses "would"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google suggestions are based on what other people search for and, if there are not many pages found for the phrase you typed, for phrases with a much larger hit count in the search engine. This doesn't necessarily mean that your phrase is wrong, so don't rely on Google to correct your sentences in that way. It can, however, be useful to check how frequently a certain phrase is used by searching for two different phrases and comparing the amount of hits you get on Google.

Now, there is a difference between the sentences when using *could* or *would*:
The verb *could* expresses **ability** or **possibility** whereas *would* expresses a **hypothetical situation**. This is also why *would* is often accompanied by an *if-clause* in which you find that the condition for that hypothetical situation. The verb *would* could also be used to express a **suggestion** or **advice**, as in the phrase *"If I were you, I **would**..."*